# Bash substitution fails in xcode build settings

Tags: ios, xcode, bash, wireguard

I am compiling WireGuard within Xcode, which requires setting up `make` as an external build tool. However, the compilation would fail every time, and I couldn't figure it out. I realized that the directory I was giving to the external tool was not correct in the log.

Following the wireguard instructions, I set the external tool directory to:
`${BUILD_DIR%Build/*}SourcePackages/checkouts/wireguard-apple/Sources/WireGuardKitGo`
This should remove the `Build/*` suffix from the `BUILD_DIR` variable, however, it instead returns empty, so the directory is passed as the relative directory:
`SourcePackages/checkouts/wireguard-apple/Sources/WireGuardKitGo`

If I instead replace the directory with:
`${BUILD_DIR}/../../SourcePackages/checkouts/wireguard-apple/Sources/WireGuardKitGo`
it works as intended. I can run `${BUILD_DIR%Build/*}` in bash and it returns as expected, so is this an issue within Xcode, am I not formatting the substitution correctly, or am I off base entirely?